# "npm start" doesn't work on Windows, altough it works on Linux and OSX.

Tags: node.js, windows, reactjs, npm

I've created a simple webapp, and it works like a charm on OSX and Linux devices. However, when I try to run "npm start" after "npm install" on Windows I recieve an error telling me that my dependency list is outdated? How can this be true if the App works on Linux and OSX?

```
C:\Users\bruker\Desktop\modalitsu-snakesandcakes-92cfc6faeef2\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\utils\verifyPackageTree.js:41
      throw new Error('This dependency list is outdated, fix it.');
      ^

Error: This dependency list is outdated, fix it.
    at depsToCheck.forEach.dep (C:\Users\bruker\Desktop\modalitsu-snakesandcakes-92cfc6faeef2\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\utils\verifyPackageTree.js:41:13)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at verifyPackageTree (C:\Users\bruker\Desktop\modalitsu-snakesandcakes-92cfc6faeef2\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\utils\verifyPackageTree.js:38:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\bruker\Desktop\modalitsu-snakesandcakes-92cfc6faeef2\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:28:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! dood@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the dood@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\bruker\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-10-25T13_45_44_574Z-debug.log
```